# Mulesoft Attribute Returning Null sqs.message.receipt.handle

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, mule-connector

I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I couldn't find much documentation.

I have a `Receive Messages` component for receiving an SQS Message, and I'm attempting to retrieve an attribute value for a downstream operation.

If I retrieve an attribute such as `ApproximateReceiveCount` with `#[attributes.SenderId]` everything works as expected.

But, if I attempt to get `sqs.message.receipt.handle` with `#[attributes.sqs.message.receipt.handle]` it returns null. Running in debug, I can see that there is a value for `sqs.message.receipt.handle`

Is there something special I need to do with attributes that have multiple `.`? What would the term be for this type of attribute for further research?

Comment: How do you see the value for the attribute? In this case a screenshot of the attribute list maybe appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dots are part of the key then try:

```
#[ attributes["sqs.message.receipt.handle"] ]
```

or

```
#[ attributes.`sqs.message.receipt.handle` ]
```